# How to run a function if a button is not clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#RunCode").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('clicked')) {
        console.log("Is clicked");
        $(".documentWrite").text("Is clicked");
    } else {
        $this.data('clicked', true);
        console.log("Is not clicked");
        $(".documentWrite").text("Is NOT clicked");
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG6dC/)

When I click on button I get *"Is NOT clicked"*, if I click again I get *"Is clicked"*. 
Why do I get the code of unclick when the button is clicked?

Comment: Why are you using a click-handling method to work out if an element's been clicked? If it hasn't been clicked the handler wouldn't be triggered. What is it that you're really trying to do?

Comment: Thanks! please read my comment under the answer of Sparky. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Why do I get the code of unclick when the button is clicked?"*

Because your conditional logic is flawed.

```
$("#RunCode").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('clicked')) { //<- FAILS on first click. 'data' is not yet set.
        console.log("Is clicked");
        $(".documentWrite").text("Is clicked");
    } else {
        $this.data('clicked', true);
        console.log("Is not clicked");
        $(".documentWrite").text("Is NOT clicked");
    }
});
```

The `data` called `'clicked'` is not `true` on the first click; you are only ***setting*** it `true` on first click.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"How to run a function if a button is not clicked?"*

What does this even mean?  The code you've presented to us is entirely contained within a `click` event handler function.  In other words, the function depends solely on the click event actually occurring.  (It can never run without a click)

If you don't want to run the function on a click, then how?

Comment: Thank you so much for your good explanation! I am using a jQuery function that doesn't have the destroy method. So I need to click on a button to activate the function, if is not clicked the function does not execute (an empty `else` statement).

Comment: I tried to create two buttons: one to activate and one to deactivate the function (but as I said, the function does not have the destroy method). I tried with return false but doesn't work so I can't deactivate the function.

Comment: This is why I wanted to try if statement in the click event.